# Rails uninitialized constant when instantiating class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a new class in my Rails application under a folder structure of app/datatables

The class is saved in a file in this directory and it is saved as DatasetIndexDatatable.rb

The contents of the class file is as follows:

```
class DatasetIndexDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

end
```

When I try to instantiate this class from a controller in my application, Rails gives an error:

```
uninitialized constant DatadescriptionController::DatasetIndexDatatable
```

The code in the controller which attempts to instantiate the new class is as follows:

```
class DatadescriptionController < ApplicationController
  layout "datadescription"

  def index
respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: DatasetIndexDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end

end
```

Why can't Rails see the new class?  I have tried adding the folder containing the class to the config.autoload_paths variable in application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib
                            #{config.root}/datatables)
```

but the same error occurs.  I have also tried instantiating the new class in the controller using the global namespace:

```
format.json { render json: ::DatasetIndexDatatable.new(view_context) }
```

and using the containing folder for the class as a namespace:

```
format.json { render json: Datatables::DatasetIndexDatatable.new(view_context) }
```

all to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question became my answer :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The file is named incorrectly. Instead of:

```
DatasetIndexDatatable.rb
```

Call it:

```
dataset_index_datatable.rb
```

This is a Rails standard naming convention. If you define a `CamelCase` class, the file that contains the definition should be named `camel_case.rb` which is lower case with underscore (*a.k.a.*, snake case).

Comment: Nice, in my case i had XxxDataTable, so be careful copying code from place to place, because this little difference can take you lot of time. Thanks, this saved me lot of time!

Comment: As a Rails noob...I just want to say that this trips me up every time!  In JS, the filename "should" match...but doesn't have to.

Comment: @WayneF.Kaskie Rails follows a specific [convention over configuration](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#convention-over-configuration) philosophy. Deviating from the conventions can be quite arduous and painful. But adhering to them can make life simple. :)